# Parse Error Creating AWS Event From the CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create an event using the AWS CLI. When I issue this command:

```
aws events put-targets --rule Rotate-Old-Access-Keys-Notification-Scheduler --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:12345678910:function:rotate-old-access-keys-notification-sender" --profile=lab
```

I get the error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--targets': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
Id
  ^
```

How can I fix this command so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue while you are trying to parse profile to your command. Below command should work.

```
aws events put-targets --rule Rotate-Old-Access-Keys-Notification-Scheduler --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:12345678910:function:rotate-old-access-keys-notification-sender" --profile lab
```